Add kubernates DNS to name resolvers of resolved
I have a minikube ingress for the host "some.test" and I would like the machine where minikube is installed to resolve that host. Following the minikube ingress documentation I ran:
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d
sudo tee /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/minikube.conf << EOF
[Resolve]
DNS=$(minikube ip)
Domains=~test
EOF
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved

Which correctly writes the configuration in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/minikube.conf.
Restarting systemd-resolved I was able to resolve some.test and to curl it to get the right answer from the backend service associated with the ingress. Unfortunately I was not able to resolve public IP's anymore (like google).
How can I be able to resolve both the minikube and public hosts ?
I've also tried to edit /etc/resolv.conf directly, but when I put the minikube dns as first I can only resolve some.test and if I put it as last I can only resolve public hosts. I've also tried editing /etc/systemd/resolv.conf with same results
Edit (solved by grawity_u1686 answer)
grawity_u1686 answer solved the problem I will just write a summary of the actions i took.
First I installed dnsmasq and edited /etc/dnsmasq.conf as follows:
interface=lo

bind-interfaces

listen-address=127.0.0.1

domain=local

domain-needed

bogus-priv

dhcp-range=192.168.49.10,192.168.49.200,255.255.255.0

server=8.8.8.8

server=/.test/<minikube ip>

Then I restart dnsmasq daemon. Last step was to set DNS=127.0.0.1 in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and restart resolved daemon.
Optional
enable dnsmasq at startup

The order does not matter, as "No such domain" is generally considered a final answer (even if negative) and DNS resolvers do not retry a different server in such situations. This applies also to systemd-resolved; it expects all specified DNS servers to be capable of providing the same data.
Systemd-resolved supports domain-based routing of DNS requests, but this is tied to network interfaces. You cannot have multiple separate (domain, server) sets in the global configuration – instead each interface has its own such set.
So if minikube somehow creates a dedicated network interface (e.g. a bridge or a tap), then it's possible to define the ~test domain and the minikube DNS server for that network interface, either through D-Bus API (resolvectl dns docker0 … and resolvectl domain …) or through systemd-networkd .network files (in some situations, if it won't cause a conflict).
If there is no separate network interface, you will need some other resolver that can do that kind of domain-based DNS routing. Dnsmasq is a common choice, with its server=/test/1.2.3.4 configuration, although I've used Unbound and BIND at different times as well. In this case, you would configure systemd-resolved to use Dnsmasq, and Dnsmasq to use the real DNS servers.

As minikube ip is 192.168.49.2 and ifconfig lists this bridge
"br-875257e1d91d: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 192.168.49.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.49.255"
I've tried resolvectl dns br-875257e1d91d 192.168.49.2 but this results in adding nameserver 192.168.49.2 to resolve.conf resulting in resolving public hosts but not some.test, was this this suggestions regarding D-Bus API or am I mistaken?

Yes, but it sounds like your resolv.conf is set up to bypass systemd-resolved, in which case any of the systemd-resolved-specific features of course won't work. You need to use the 'stub' resolv.conf that points only to 127.0.0.53 and nowhere else.

(For example, it should be symlinked to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf if you use resolved only – or to /run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf if you use NM.)
